# What does the expression $A^c$ mean in this context?

Tags: notation

In a maths question, I had $A$ with a superscript of $c$, like this:
$$A^c$$
What does this mean? In a Venn Diagram $A =$ to 5 and 6.

Comment: is it complement?

Comment: It is not a compliment.

Comment: It is not a compliment, but the question was whether it was a complement?

Answer (score 3):

$A^c$ means the *complement* of the set $A$. It is the set of all elements (in some universal set) that are not in $A$.

Comment: It is the set of all elements that are not in A respect to A's universal set M.

Comment: Oh. THANK YOU. You saved a lot of marks in my grade :D

Comment: @William your two comments are in diverge :)